# Joins That Includes Non-matching Record

Tags: sql

I have a tag list.  I want to list all tags and the total count each tag is used.

I can get the result using a LEFT JOIN.  My problem is that my statement does not include tags that are not used.  If possible, I also wanted to show all tags (used and not used in one SQL statement).

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT tag.name, COUNT(tag.id)
FROM tags
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.tagid = tags.id
WHERE posts.published = 'yes'
GROUP BY posts.tagid
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `WHERE` condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(p.tagid)
FROM tags t LEFT JOIN
     posts p
     ON p.tagid = t.id AND p.published = 'yes'
GROUP BY t.name, t.tagid;
```

The general rule is:  For a `LEFT JOIN` filters on the *first* table go in the `WHERE` clause.  Filters on the *second* table go in the `ON` clause.  Otherwise, the `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join.

Notes:

- The `COUNT()` now counts matches from the *second* table, so it can return `0` values.
- The unaggregated `SELECT` column in consistent with the `GROUP BY`.
- I added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: …and `COUNT(p.tagid)` doesn't count NULL tagids, so you get a zero count for a tagid with no matching post…?

Comment: What if I added another table: poststags.  This table holds postid and tagid so mutiple tags can be assigned to a post or to a lot of posts.

Comment: @Ben . . . Then you would have a different question, and that should be asked as a *new* question.  However, the answer would really be quite similar, just having another `join` basically.

Comment: Thank you, @GordonLinoff.  I'll have to ask a new question.  I did try adding another join but I'm not getting the expected result.